# How to get a string value in android from ashx page?

Tags: android, ashx

I have a TextView in my android appliation. Now I need to get a value from an ashx page. When I open that ashx page in browser, I can see that it is showing only a single value. I need to show that value in my TextView.

Please help me out...

Comment: can you show me the ashx page...with url ....?

Comment: http://173.45.66.154/VSServices/Export.ashx?f=GetClientBalance&pin=rsbtest&includeCurrency=true

Comment: @AngadTiwari: This is the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get internet permission....and just run this code...

```
        try
        {
            HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request=new HttpGet("http://173.45.66.154/VSServices/Export.ashx?f=GetClientBalance&pin=rsbtest&includeCurrency=true");
            HttpResponse response=client.execute(request);

            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            String resonseText=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            textviewObject.setText(resonseText);

            entity.consumeContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString()  , 0).show();
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: :I've taken internet permission and tried with the code u given.. But getting error: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: delete targetSdkversion line from manifest file...as the network operation is not allow to run on main thread..or you can make separate thread for that code

Comment: It is not working. I have tried to call the function using another thread, also tried to call the function from another activity but getting the same error

Comment: ok let me try first ..mine eclipse is bit problematic right now...i will show you....